Questions on proving that every infinite set of real numbers has a countable dense subset
I have been learning answers provided in this question. The answer from Fishbane uses this definition of a dense subset.

A subset $B$ of $A$ is dense in $A$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and any $x \in A$, there exists an element $y \in B$ such that $|x-y|<\varepsilon$.

I am currently using the book of Strichartz, "The Way of Analysis" (revised edition) in which a dense subset is defined as follows

A subset $B$ of $A$ is dense in $A$ if $A$ is contained in the closure of $B$, i.e. $B \subseteq A \subseteq \bar{B}$.

To prevent any difference between definitions, I will also provide the definitions of open sets, closed sets, limit points of a set, and closure. I will put these definitions in this image so that this question is not too long.
I have proved that both definitions of dense subsets are equivalent, i.e if I am following the definition in Strichartz, then

A subset $B$ of $A$ is dense in $A$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and any $x \in A$, there exists an element $y \in B$ such that $|x-y|<\varepsilon$.

proof. $(\Rightarrow)$ Let $B$ be a dense subset of $A$. Then, $B \subseteq A \subseteq \bar{B}$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$. Thus, either $x \in B$ or $x$ is a limit point of $B$. If $x \in B$, then choose $y = x$ and we are done. If $x$ is a limit point of $B$, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists y_n \neq x \ni |x-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}$. By Archimedian property, this immediately applies for every $\varepsilon > 0$.
$(\Leftarrow)$ Let $A$ and the subset $B$ of $A$ have the property that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and any $x \in A$, there exists an element $y \in B$ such that $|x-y|<\varepsilon$. Let $x \in A$ be arbitrary, then either $x \in B$ or $x \in A\backslash B$. It is trivial if $x \in B$, so that $x \in \bar{B}$. If $x \in A\backslash B$, then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists y_n \in B \ni |x-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}$ as $\frac{1}{n} > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $x \in A\backslash B$, it must be $y_n \neq x$ for all $n$, hence $x$ is a limit point of $B$, implying that $x \in \bar{B}$.
Now I will provide my proof that every infinite set of real numbers has a countable dense subset using the equivalence between definitions. Let $A$ be an infinite set and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This proof is actually the detailed version of Fishbane's answer, so I immediately start with the construction of $B_n \subseteq A$ with property that $B_n$ is countable and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists y \in B_n \ni |x-y|<\frac{1}{n}$. Let $Z_n$ be the set defined below
$$Z_n = \left\{ \left[\dfrac{k}{n},\dfrac{k+1}{n}\right) \cap A : k \in \mathbb{Z} \right\} \backslash \{\emptyset\}.$$
Surely there are infinitely (countably to be precise) many integers $k$ such that $\left[\dfrac{k}{n},\dfrac{k+1}{n}\right) \cap A$ are nonempty since $A$ is infinite. Therefore, by axiom of countable choice, we can construct a countable set $B_n$ from $Z_n$, say
$$B_n = \{ x_n^{(k_1)}, x_n^{(k_2)}, x_n^{(k_3)}, ...  \}.$$
Now, since $x \in A$, then $nx \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, there is an integer $k'$ such that
$$ k' \leq nx < k'+1 \Longrightarrow \dfrac{k'}{n} < x <\dfrac{k'+ 1}{n}.$$
This imply that $\left[\dfrac{k'}{n},\dfrac{k'+1}{n}\right) \cap A$ is nonempty, hence there exists $x_n^{(k')} \in B_n$ such that $x_n^{(k')} \in \left[\dfrac{k'}{n},\dfrac{k'+1}{n}\right) \cap A$. Therefore, $|x - x_n^{(k')}|<\frac{1}{n}.$
Continuing for every natural number $n$, we have $B = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n$, which is countable since it is a countable union of countable sets, that satisfies the property

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and any $x \in A$, there exists an element $y \in B$ such that $|x-y|<\frac{1}{n}$. By Archimedian property, this immediately applies for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

Therefore, we obtain a countable subset $B$ of $A$ that satisfies the desired property, so it is proved that every infinite set of real numbers has a countable dense subset.
My questions:
Is my proof correct? The part that bothers me the most is that the implication of $\left[\dfrac{k'}{n},\dfrac{k'+1}{n}\right) \cap A$ being nonempty after we know that $x \in \left[\dfrac{k'}{n},\dfrac{k'+1}{n}\right)$. Do we have to guarantee that the element $x_n^{(k')}$ differs from $x$ if $\left[\dfrac{k'}{n},\dfrac{k'+1}{n}\right) \cap A$ contains more than one point? even though, the equivalence states that it is sufficient to choose an element in $B$ without any restriction that it has to differ from $x$ on certain condition.
I also tried the hint provided by Mariano Suárez-Álvarez. He suggests another approach to constructing the countable subset $B$ of $A$ using nonempty intersection of rational intervals and $A$. This also leads to the same problem when implying that some $(p,q) \cap A$ is nonempty, hence take $x_{p,q}$ so that $|x - x_{p,q}| < \frac{1}{n}$.
Any clarification or insight would be appreciated.

I’d try a model theoretic construction, a la back-and-forth.  Construct the dense subset explicitly by “filling in” the gaps.  This should be fairly direct; at each step we add a point to the subset that partially satisfies the density requirement for some remaining region that is not yet covered.  In countably-many steps we can clearly get within epsilon of any point in our original set (think: binary search).

To guarantee $x\neq x_{p,q}$, the limit point gymnastics,  you need to add the assumption that $x$ is not an isolated point and be a bit careful in the choices made earlier. The nice thing about the definitions from Strichartz (and many other books) is you don’t need to worry about limit points.

Your proof looks fine overall. A few points:

Surely there are infinitely (countably to be precise) many integers $k$ such that $\left[ \frac{k}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right) \cap A$ are nonempty since $A$ is infinite.

This isn't true. Consider for instance $A = [0, 1]$, which is infinite. For any given $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, the number of such intervals that intersects $A$ is $n + 1$. Importantly, it is finite: countable, but not infinite.
This is a small point and doesn't really affect the rest of your proof.

Do we have to guarantee that the element $x_n^{(k')}$ differs from $x$ if $\left[ \frac{k'}{n}, \frac{k' + 1}{n} \right) \cap A$ contains more than one point?

It's perfectly fine for $x$ not to differ from $x_n^{(k')}$, even if the intersection contains more than one point. Let's take your definition of "dense subset" from Strichartz:

A subset $B \subseteq A$ is dense in $A$ if $A$ is contained in the closure of $B$; i.e., $B \subseteq A \subseteq {\rm Cl} B$.

Letting $x \in A$ be arbitrary, we just require that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, the neighborhood $B_d (x, \varepsilon)$ of $x$ intersects $B$. If we get $x \in B$, all the better!

I think the author also allows $n$ to change, at least that was my interpretation.

@Steen82 I'm not sure I follow. Yes, $n$ is allowed to change, but as long as for each $n$, a point $x_n^k$ is selected in each interval $\left[ \frac{k}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right)$ in which it is possible, then taking the union you get a dense subset. Can you please elaborate?

^Typo: selected in each interval $\left[ \frac{k}{n}, \frac{k + 1}{n} \right) \cap A$ in which it is possible
